# How can I modify Info.plist under EI Capitan 10.11.4 or Later

Tags: macos, hardware, permission

This problem bothers me since I tried to add a hardware(smartcard device) information to the support list, so that I can use this smartcard device under my macintosh. But I don't have permission to modify this list file(Info.plist) on EI Capitan 10.11.4 or 10.11.5. Before 10.11.4, there is no this permission thing, I can't see why apple doing this.

Anyone knows how to modify the Info.plist(directory: "/usr/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/")?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's wrong about following the error message? Depending on your SIP status you may have to disable it addtionally!

Comment: @klanomath You see, I am new in Macintosh and I didn't know there is a System Integrity Protection. Anyway, now I know and the answer GoodDog gave is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit (as suggested by klanomath) is likely System Integrity Protection, that protects (except others) also the /usr directory. To switch it off

1. Switch off your Mac
2. Boot into recovery (when you press power button, you should be already holding <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys, hold them as long as the display is clear white)
3. In the recovery system, go in the menubar to Utilities > Terminal
4. Terminal window will pop-up. Enter:

   `csrutil disable`
5. Confirm with enter
6. Close Terminal, restart the computer through Apple logo in top left corner

From here on, the SIP is disabled and you can edit your file. It should be noted, that after you are done with your modifications, you should definitely re-enable the SIP. The method is same as above, the only difference is that you will type into Terminal:

```
csrutil enable
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it's exactly what I needed. And your English is far more better than mine. BTW, your account name here is cute :p.

Comment: ... you are too kind :)